# can OptimisticLockException occur if app srv Isolation level is set to READ COMMITTED?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, openjpa, isolation-level

I am using Websphere application server 7.0.0.0.9 with ;OpenJPA 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT'. 
I have Set property of jdbc data source webSphereDefaultIsolationLevel=2 (READ COMMITTED). 
I have this question because My understanding is the OptimasticLockException occurs if there is race to commit the same row by multiple thread. 
But I think this situation should never occur if isolation level app server is set to READ COMMITTED.

This is exception I am getting..

```
<openjpa-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:907835 fatal store error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OptimisticLockException: An optimistic lock violation was detected when flushing object instance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have this question because my understanding is the `OptimisticLockException` occurs if there is race to commit the same row by multiple thread.

Yes, an `OptimisticLockException` will be thrown if the `Version` attribute of an entity is higher (i.e. has been modified by another transaction) at commit time than when it was read. This is illustrated by the figure below (borrowed from [JPA 2.0 Concurrency and locking](https://web.archive.org/web/20131212234526/https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and)):

[image]

> But I think this situation should never occur if isolation level app server is set to READ COMMITTED.

Why? When using a [READ COMMITTED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#READ_COMMITTED) isolation level, [non-repeatable reads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Read_Committed_.28Non-repeatable_reads.29) may occur but:

1. This won't affect in memory representation of data (`e1` in the above example)
2. Most of time, you don't re-read data

- And even if you do (and perform a non-repeatable read), an entity might still get modified by another thread before you commit changes.

To sum up, READ COMMITTED won't prevent `OptimisticLockException`.